# How to dynamically databind treeView in WPF MVVM pattern

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I'm a beginner just starting to learn WPF.
I was assigned a project.
I need to read the sheet of the excel file and display the sheet and the columns of the sheet in the tree view.

What I'm curious about is

1. How should I dynamically update the treeview?
2. How to hierarchically display the text read from Excel in the tree view

If you've done something similar, could you give me a hint?

I am using ObservableCollection to bind data to treeview.

Every time the data changes, you have to bind the data of the userControl that includes the tree view, but it is difficult to develop with WPF after developing with javascript.

In addition, if there are any references I can refer to, please recommend anything.

I hope the peace of those who answered.

Comment: [Data binding overview (WPF .NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-7.0), [TreeView Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/treeview-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)